# Comparison or Assignment?

Tags: sql

```
  SELECT ProductId,
       ProductName,
       CategoryId,
       UnitPrice,
       (
           SELECT avg(UnitPrice) 
             FROM products
            WHERE (CategoryId = p.CategoryId) 
       )
       AS avgUnitPricePerCategory
  FROM products p
```

In above query, what I want to find is to print the category averages next to each product. It works but what I don't understand is in this part
`(CategoryId = p.CategoryId)` does it return TRUE or FALSE? Shouldn't it return CategoryID of the main query row?

Note: My question is does the subquery reduce to

```
SELECT avg(UnitPrice) 
       FROM products
       WHERE (TRUE)
```

or

```
SELECT avg(UnitPrice) 
       FROM products
       WHERE (CategoryID=1)
```

for each row in the main query?

Comment: Are you aware that it's called a [Correlated Subquery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery) and is reasonably well described on wikipedia.

Comment: I know what is correlated subquery is. What I want to know if  CategoryID=p.CategoryID is an assignment operator or a comparison operator?  I mean does it mean if CategoryID=1 for example or does it return TRUE if both are same? Everywhere it is written = is a comparison operator in SQL. If it is a comparison operator and returning true, how it takes an average value of prices of a TRUE CategoryID?This is why I am asking. @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: Imagine that it was an assignment operator. How then would you write any sort of `where` clause?

Comment: I'm struggling to make sense of your literal question because I cannot comprehend how assignment would ever be an option you'd be thinking about.

Comment: Isn't this an assignment for CategoryID? SELECT avg(UnitPrice) 
             FROM products
            WHERE (CategoryId = 1)

Comment: `WHERE (TRUE)` would select all rows, `WHERE (CategoryID=1)` would select those where the ID is equal to 1 - isn't that obvious? Also, please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subquery

```
       SELECT avg(UnitPrice) 
       FROM products
       WHERE (CategoryId = ...)
```

selects all products where the `CategoryId` equals to `...`.

So in the total query this has the effect that for every `p` record the average of the UnitPrice for its `p.CategoryId` is calculated.

You can also write the query as a join

```
SELECT ProductId,
       ProductName,
       CategoryId,
       UnitPrice,
       AVG(r.UnitPrice) AS avgUnitPricePerCategory
FROM products p
JOIN products a ON a.CategoryId = p.CategoryId
```

Comment: Then is this sign (=) an assignment? I mean like WHERE (CategoryId = 1)? Then not comparison. source: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-operators.htm   This site states that (=) is a comparison operator in SQL.

Comment: No, equality comparison operator. It is a filtering condition. In all cases here. WHERE is always a condition, and the query in general does not assign, just outputs the result of walking through tables.